# Why is anchor pane transparent, while split pane is not? (javafx)

Tags: javafx, pane

I would like to create a window, that consists of two anchor panes.

I would like to set a background image for the root anchor pane, and put the second one above it. So I would expect, that the preview should look now: A white space(second anchor pane) surrounded by the edges of the root anchor pane's background image as a frame. But the second anchor pane seems to be transparent, as I can see the whole background image if I do tests.

No opacity or such is set...

(I don't get this, because the split plane for example is not transparent... Though I start to get it, that these panes and split pane are not the same in terms of some qualities, but I don't know why it is so.)

What do you think, what is the best practice for solving the former issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Pane` subclasses are transparent by default. `Control` subclasses are styled by the default CSS stylesheet, so their background color is determined by the style. `SplitPane` is a control, so its background color is determined by the [default CSS stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css). This sets the background color to the looked-up color `-fx-background` (line 611), which defaults to a darker version (26.4% intensity, line 102) of the base color (`#ececec`).

The best way to change the background of your anchor pane is with an external css file. (This means you can separate the style/look of the application from the actual application code.) Add an id to the anchor pane:

```
AnchorPane maskingPane = new AnchorPane();
maskingPane.setId("masking-pane");
```

and then in your external css file, you can do

```
#masking-pane {
    -fx-background-color: white ;
}
```

or, if you want to get the same color as the split pane:

```
#masking-pane {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
}
```

The `id` should be unique; if you have multiple panes that you want to make the same color, you can add a style class to them instead:

```
AnchorPane maskingPane = new AnchorPane();
maskingPane.getStyleClass().add("masking-pane");
```

and then the css looks like

```
.masking-pane {
    -fx-background-color: white ;
}
```

The Oracle JavaFX tutorial has a [section on styling the application with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG)

Comment: I'd like to do the reverse: I have a SplitPane inside an AnchorPane. The AnchorPane has the gradient background I want, but the SplitPane is opaque. Is there a way to make the background of the SplitPane transparent? If I adjust the opacity of the SplitPane itself to be transparent, it seems that all of the controls in the SplitPane also become transparent.